# Prolog List, check additions to list

Tags: list, prolog

I have created a predicate that will check whether all the items in a list satisfy a condition.

For this example, the predicate checks that all elements are in multiples of two `Check_Multiples/1`, which works quite well.

How would I check to see what item could be added to the beginning or the end of the list, and still satisfy the predicate?

I am trying to make the return a list.

For example:

```
[2,4,6]
```

should return `[8]` as (as the predicate does not allow 0)

```
[6,8,10]
```

should return `[4,12]`

Comment: If the predicate, such as `Check_Multiples/1`, is properly defined with CLP(FD) and has well-defined rules what that predicate means, then this would simply be, `begin_or_end(L, BE) :- append(L, [Y], L1), findall(X, (Check_Multiples([X|L]) ; Check_Multiples(L1)), BE).`.

Comment: Oops that should be, `begin_or_end(L, BE) :- findall(X, (Check_Multiples([X|L]) ; append(L, [X], L1), Check_Multiples(L1)), BE).`

Comment: Thank you for your response I will try that. I'm afraid I don't know what CLD is and will have to read some more.My naive approach was to try to call the Check_Multiples predicate with a variable both before and after the list.

Comment: Just google "prolog CLPFD" or "prolog finite domains" and you'll find a lot of goodies. It lets you write relational statements for arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick, given that Check_Multiples checks if every element of the list is a multiple of two in an ascending order. I'm guessing that was a condition, otherwise if lists such as [4, 6, 4, 4, 8] were allowed you could just check if every element modulus 2 is equal to 0.

```
additionsToList([H|T], ResultList) :-
    Check_Multiples([H|T]),
    firstElement(H, First),
    lastElement(T, Last),
    append([First],[Last], Z),
    flatten(Z, ResultList).

firstElement(2, []).
firstElement(First, X) :-
    X is First-2.

lastElement([H|[]], X) :-
    X is H+2.
lastElement([_|T], X) :-
    lastElement(T, X).
```